# Triple output video card

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I currently have a dual monitor setup, but I would like to expand to three monitors. My motherboard only supports one PCI-E card, so I was wondering if it's possible to head a triple-output video card?

It seems almost all cards are dual-output, but I haven't been able to find any triple-output cards.

Comment: Related: *[Three Monitors For Every User](https://blog.codinghorror.com/three-monitors-for-every-user/)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many cards offer 3 display ports, but most can only drive 2 displays at a time.

> I would like to expand to 3 monitors.

For this, you'll want a **[ATI Radeon HD 5xxx](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5670-specifications.aspx)**.

> Drive three displays simultaneously
>   with independent resolutions, refresh
>   rates, color controls, and video
>   overlays.

The **ATI Radeon HD 5670** would be the entry level card, price around **[$100](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?nm_mc=AFC-TechBargains&cm_mmc=AFC-TechBargains-_-NA-_-NA-_-NA&Item=N82E16814102871)**.

[image]

The **[ATI Radeon HD 5750](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5750/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5750-overview.aspx)** costs around **[$135](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102859)**.

[image]

All ATI Radeon HD 5xxx support **[Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity.aspx)** multi-display technology:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Matrox](http://www.matrox.com) also specializes in multi-monitor video cards. The [M9138 LP PCIe x16](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/m_series/m9138lppciex16/?productTabs=1#close) seems a good fit.

> The Matrox M9138 LP PCIe x16 triple
>   graphics card renders pristine image
>   quality on up to three DisplayPort
>   monitors at resolutions up to 2560 x
>   1600 per output, for an exceptional
>   multi-monitor user experience. With 1
>   GB of memory and advanced desktop
>   management features, such as
>   **independent** and stretched desktop
>   modes, the M9138 drives business,
>   industrial, and government
>   applications with extraordinary
>   performance. Its low-profile form
>   factor makes it easy to integrate into
>   a wide variety of systems. It offers
>   multiple operating system support, and
>   can be paired with another M-Series
>   card for additional monitor support.

You may also be interested in one of their other products, the [TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/):

> Matrox TripleHead2Go is an external multi-display
>   upgrade that adds up to three monitors to your notebook 
>   or desktop computer. Ideal for professionals requiring 
>   more desktop space for maximum productivity increases
>    and gamers wanting a totally immersive 
>   experience, this small box lets you run different
>   applications on each display or view 
>   one application across up to three monitors. 
>   Available in DisplayPort, Digital, or 
>   Analog Editions.

[image]

Comment: $300 for that??? don't know about you, but i prefer a high-powered 3D card with Eyefinity and directX 11 support for $100 :)

Comment: I never said it was cheap. The advantage is it can easily be used with any system which only has 1 monitor output, so you can move it from your laptop to your desktop to your work computer easily. Video cards on the other hand, not so much.

Comment: i know, they're cool for laptops, but for a desktop, i'd rather not. (and aren't they a Canadian company? :) i remember when they were the big kids on the GPU block ... but their glory has somewhat faded, and not exactly undeserved (long story).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use [Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia)-specific featuers, the [GTX 590](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_500_series#GeForce_500_.285xx.29_series) and [GTX 295](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_200_series#GeForce_200_Series) (both close to $800) both also support simultaneous triple head output. See Nvidia's [surround technology page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-surround-system-requirements.html), and click "Connector Recommendations" for more information.

Comment: nVidia's 670/680 single GPU cards support 3 DVI/HDMI outputs.  It's possible the kepler based low/mid range end parts will as well (the ones based on the older Fermi design won't); but I can't find any specific information on the low end ones and the mid range parts aren't out yet.