# Recommend single 3-monitor video card for 32-bit Windows XP for Software Development/Office Applications?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dell-precision

I'm purchasing a new computer from Dell:

> Dell Precision T1500 Base for Intel
>   H57 Chipset  Quad Core Processor Core
>   i5-750,2.66GHz,8MB Cache, 32-bit

for two of these monitors:
Dell U2211H 1920x1080   21.5" DisplayPort

and in the future a possible third monitor.

I'm not a gamer.

I'm technically challenged.  What will work with the Dell for Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that workstation only has a single PCI-Express x16 slot, you're probably stuck using either an AMD/ATI graphics card with [EyeFinity](http://sites.amd.com/us/underground/products/eyefinity/whatiseyefinity/Pages/what-is-eyefinity.aspx) support or a Matrox DualHead2Go or TripleHead2Go to add your third monitor.  Of these options, the EyeFinity card would probably be preferable.  See this similar question: [Triple output video card](https://superuser.com/questions/97567/triple-output-video-card)